# How can I access method attributes in method A after returning from method B in AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have method A in my Spring backend project that should be invoked after execution of different method - B. Returning type of method B is void, but I need to pass one input parameter from method B to method A, after successful execution of method B.

Method B:

```
void invite(int eventId, int userId, Integer[] invitees,
        EventInvitationMethod push, String content);
```

Method A:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(* xyz.zzz.api.event.service.EventService.invite(..))")
public void newInvitation(InputParameter of B - int userId){
     ///Do something with userId
}
```

Is it possible to do that? I need to be sure, that method B was executed successfully to process method A.

Any help will be great.

Comment: Why don't you call newInvitation(userId) last line on method invite()?

Comment: Because invite invokes repository, which calls stored procedure in DB as a native query, so I don't have implementation of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved problem like this:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* xyz.zzz.api.event.service.EventService.invite(..))")
public void newInvitation(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    ///I am working with args, looking for an instance of Integer[]
}
```

Hope it will help somebody.